# Line behind title when the container has an image as background

Tags: html, css

I'm looking to add a line behind a title (left and right). Usually I can just use for the title the background color of the container and some padding and manage to solve this problem like this:

[strike through example](http://theleggett.com/explanations/strikethrough/)

but in this situation the container of the title is not a solid color it has an image  as background. Any ideas about how to solve this?

Comment: So what exactly was your question again?

Comment: The container of the title has as background an image and not a solid color so I cannot just add padding to the title and background color, I need the title background to be transparent

Comment: Once again: http://css-tricks.com/line-on-sides-headers/

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Changed CSS for `.line` to `width: 10%` to fix problems with narrow viewports, as per noticed in comments.

Here's a solution using two `<div>`s as lines, and then centering the heading using a really wide `.wide-wrapper`.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="wide-wrapper">
        <div class="line"></div>
        <h1>Heading Title</h1>
        <div class="line"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.wide-wrapper {
    left: -1200%;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    width: 2500%;
}

.line {
    border-top: 3px solid grey;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 10%;
}

h1 {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/168vg6nz/2/).

Comment: This wouldn't work very nicely responsively, when viewed on a mobile. When you resize the width of the HTML pane to mobile-like width, it makes the title jump over to the right off the screen.

Comment: @Lee Thanks for checking. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Here is working example.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Line</title>
    <style>


    .heading {
        position: relative;
    }
    .heading h1 {
      font-family:Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
      font-weight:100;
      font-size:36px;
      text-align: center;
      background: #fff;
      position: relative;
      display: block;
      max-width: 300px;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
    .heading:before{
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: 1px;
        background: #000;
        top: 50%;
    }

    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="heading">
      <h1>Heading Title</h1>
    </div><!-- div.heading -->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Mind if I tweak this a little?

Comment: Yes, of course, feel free with it.

Comment: There is a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/salman/hyd59csp/. I added display inline-block and moved text-align to the parent. Rest is the same.

Comment: The background of the h1 cannot be a solid color. It has to be transparent so that the image behind it can be seen

Comment: Yes, I have forgotten about that.

Answer (score 0):

### HTML

```
<div class="heading"><h1>Hello World</h1></div>
```

### CSS

```
.heading {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.heading h1 {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;  
}

.heading h1::before,
.heading h1::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    height: 1px;
    background: #fff;
    top: 15px;
    width: 9999px;
}

.heading h1::before {
    right: 100%;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.heading h1::after {
    left: 100%;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/v3vk7goj/).